# AndEngine Full Image Background (width and height)

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, game-engine

I'm really new to Android game development and I am facing an issue about screen image background.

Here is my full class code that extends `SimpleBaseGameActivity`
**UPDATED camera width and height that corresponds to image dimensions**

```
private final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;//800;
private final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 836; //1280;

private Camera mCamera;

//Background variables
private TextureRegion region;

private Scene mScene;

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    this.mCamera = new Camera(0,0,CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_SENSOR, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera);
}

@Override
protected void onCreateResources() throws IOException {
    BitmapTextureAtlas atlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(),CAMERA_WIDTH+CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT+CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    this.region = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(atlas,this,"snow_bg.png",0,0);
    atlas.load();

}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    this.mScene = new Scene();
    Sprite sprite = new Sprite(0,0,region,this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    this.mScene.setBackground(new SpriteBackground(sprite));

    return this.mScene;
}
```

The issue that I am facing is the background image, which is not in full screen. I've been searching how to stretch image background in `AndEngine` but I haven't found any good resources.

Here is the screen shot.

[image]

But the image full screen view is

[image]

Please give me some advise what should I do or sample codes to achieve my goal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Łukasz Motyczka i was able to make it by making my sprite

```
float centerX = CAMERA_WIDTH/2;
float centerY = CAMERA_HEIGHT/2;

Sprite sprite = new Sprite(centerX,centerY,this.region, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

Here's my full code

```
private final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;
private final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 836;

private Camera mCamera;
private TextureRegion region;

private Scene mScene;

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    this.mCamera = new Camera(0,0,CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_SENSOR, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera);
}

@Override
protected void onCreateResources() throws IOException {
    BitmapTextureAtlas atlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(),CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    this.region = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(atlas,this,"snow_bg.png",0,0);
    atlas.load();

}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    this.mScene = new Scene();
    float centerX = CAMERA_WIDTH/2;
    float centerY = CAMERA_HEIGHT/2;

    Sprite sprite = new Sprite(centerX,centerY,this.region, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    this.mScene.setBackground(new SpriteBackground(sprite));

    return this.mScene;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Cute background! Second: Your region dimensions should be in power of two (256x256, 1024x512, 2048x2048 and so on). Third: What are your image dimensions? Are they same as your camera width or height? if not you can do:

```
mScene.setBackground(new SpriteBackground(this.mCamera, new Sprite(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT, this.region))); .
```

Generally idea is to set dimensions of your background too, not only its position, because it is not stretched to the size of the screen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(0,0,region,this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

to

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(0, 0, region,getWidth(), region.getHeight(), region, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```